# Error org.json.JSONException: Value <html><head><title> Error of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: java, android, json, eclipse

I have a Android app about Public Transportation, and I have a PHP script that connects to mySQL database. This is the main.java

```
package com.chera.trans;

import com.chera.trans.R;

 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.MenuInflater;
 import android.view.MenuItem;

  public class Main extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

}   
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
      inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
      return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.traseu2:
        Intent traseu2 = new Intent(this, Traseu2.class);
        this.startActivity(traseu2);
        break;
    case R.id.traseu401:
        Intent traseu401 = new Intent(this, Traseu401.class);
        this.startActivity(traseu401);
        break;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    return true;
}
```

}
And this is the code for Traseu2.java

```
package com.chera.trans;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;




 import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
 import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
  import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
   import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
  import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient; 
  import org.json.JSONArray;
   import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;




  import com.chera.trans.R;

import android.os.AsyncTask; 
import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.app.Activity;
   import android.content.Intent;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuInflater;
  import android.view.MenuItem;
  import android.widget.ListView;
 import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
  import android.widget.Toast;

 public class Traseu2 extends Activity {
 private String jsonResult;
 private String url = "http://transploiesti.tk/2.php";
 private ListView listView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.traseu2);   
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    accessWebService();
}   
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
      inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
      return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.traseu2:
        Intent traseu2 = new Intent(this, Traseu2.class);
        this.startActivity(traseu2);
        break;
    case R.id.traseu401:
        Intent traseu401 = new Intent(this, Traseu401.class);
        this.startActivity(traseu401);
        break;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    return true;
}

 // Async Task to access the web
 private class JsonReadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
  @Override
  protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
   HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
   HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(params[0]);
   try {
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    jsonResult = inputStreamToString(
      response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
   }

   catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
   return null;
  }

  private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
   String rLine = "";
   StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();
   BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

   try {
    while ((rLine = rd.readLine()) != null) {
     answer.append(rLine);
    }
   }

   catch (IOException e) {
    // e.printStackTrace();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
      "Error..." + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
   return answer;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
   ListDrwaer();
  }
 }// end async task

 public void accessWebService() {
  JsonReadTask task = new JsonReadTask();
  // passes values for the urls string array
  task.execute(new String[] { url });
 }

 // build hash set for list view
 public void ListDrwaer() {
  List<Map<String, String>> employeeList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

  try {
   JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(jsonResult);
   JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("traseudoi");

   for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
    String name = jsonChildNode.optString("Statie");
    String number = jsonChildNode.optString("Oraplecare");
    String outPut = "Autobuzul pleaca din " + name + " la ora " + number;
    employeeList.add(createEmployee("employees", outPut));
   }
  } catch (JSONException e) {
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error" + e.toString(),
     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }

  SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, employeeList,
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
    new String[] { "employees" }, new int[] { android.R.id.text1 });
  listView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);
 }

 private HashMap<String, String> createEmployee(String name, String number) {
  HashMap<String, String> employeeNameNo = new HashMap<String, String>();
  employeeNameNo.put(name, number);
  return employeeNameNo;
 }
```

}
` Why I receive this error when I m running the app? Thanks!

Comment: paste your php coding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML is not JSON, and it can not be parsed into JSONObjects. The top answer for [org.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10876079/org-json-jsonexception-value-doctype-of-type-java-lang-string-cannot-be-conve?rq=1) is pretty good at explaining this further.